# How do I create a table with a foreign key reference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are my two tables I created.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
   EmpID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   StreetAddress VARCHAR(75),
   City VARCHAR(255),
   State VARCHAR(25),
   ZipCode VARCHAR(5),
   EmployeeType VARCHAR (20),
   HourlyWage DECIMAL(18,2)
)

CREATE TABLE WagesPayable
(
   FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) REFERENCES Employee (EmpID),
   WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2),
   PayRate DECIMAL(18,2),
   TotalPayable AS (WorkedHours * PayRate),
   DateLastPaid DATETIME
)
```

Whenever I try and create the `WagesPayable` table I get the following error:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Foreign key 'EmpID' references invalid column 'EmpID' in referencing table 'WagesPayable'.

What am I missing here? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: EmpId int foreign key references Employee(EmpId)

Comment: Have a look at it: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp  and please do some research on your part before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the column before the reference.  You can do this all in one step:

```
CREATE TABLE WagesPayable
(
EmpID int REFERENCES Employee (EmpID),
WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2),
PayRate DECIMAL(18,2),
TotalPayable AS (WorkedHours * PayRate),
DateLastPaid DATETIME
)
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a0bb).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating a column EmpID for table WagesPayable.

So first you need to create the column, and then reference it as a foreign key like this :

```
CREATE TABLE WagesPayable
(
EmpID int,
WorkedHours DECIMAL(18,2),
PayRate DECIMAL(18,2),
TotalPayable AS (WorkedHours * PayRate),
DateLastPaid DATETIME,
FOREIGN KEY (EmpID) REFERENCES Employee (EmpID)
)
```